# debugging angular 'unknown provider'

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get this fileuploader plugin  working on a page (it's actually .cshtml, but hopefully that's not the source of the problem). I don't know how to debug angular references to find out what's missing.

The fileuploader does work in a different place in the app:

**markup:** Views\Shared_MasterClientLayout.cshtml

```
    <script src="@Html.GetContentPathAbsolute()/Content/lib/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>

<body id="ng-app" ng-app="clientPortal"
```

**controller:** www\public\app\disabilities\disabilities.app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('disabilities', ['angularFileUpload']);


    app.controller('disabilitiesController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$routeParams', '$fileUploader', disabilitiesController]);

    function disabilitiesController($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $fileUploader) {
    }

})();
```

But it does not work on my page:

**markup:** Views\Referral\ThankYou.cshtml

```
    <script src="@Html.GetContentPathAbsolute()/Content/lib/angular-file-upload/angular-file-upload.min.js"></script>

<div id="ng-app" ng-app="cmorApp">
```

**controller:** ReferralContent\app\CreateReferral\cm.attachmentUploadCtrl.js

```
var AttachmentUploadCtrl = ['$scope', '$http', '$fileUploader',
function ($scope, $http, $fileUploader) {
```

I get 
**Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $fileUploaderProvider <- $fileUploader**

I can see on the Sources tab in Dev tools that angular-file-upload-min.js has been loaded.

The worst part about this is a lack of consistency of implementation across pages that the various components are spread across. I know of no way to debug angular empirically.

I literally have no way to tell which of several apps is running, which controller is attached to a page and which is referring to what page.

Is there any way of inspecting a page and exposing what objects are loaded on it?

Can I write **console.log(ng-app)** and have it return 'cmorApp'?
Or **console.log(app.controller)** and have it return 'AttachmentUploadCtrl'?

Comment: You should have a look to chrome extension batarang. It's far from perfect but very usefull in some cases.

Comment: Have you tried taking the "$" off of the "$fileUploader" injection? All the docs I see have it without the $

Comment: Yes. That's seems to have done trick. Makes me wonder how it's working in other modules with the $.

Comment: And thanks for pointing me in that direction!